# Roundcube: Connection to storage server failed

Tags: debian, email

- Fresh AWS EC2 instance
- Fresh Debian install with Debian (Stretch) official AMI
- Fresh iRedAdmin install (including Roundcube)

---

- I can access iRedAdmin control panel using my internet browser
- I cannot access (any) account at Roundcube (webmail)

It displays:

> Connection to storage server failed

Comment: Usually means the user's Maildir/etc hasn't been created.  Typically an email is sent to a new user, if it is delivered OK the proper directory structure is created.  Check your mail.log for errors

Comment: When trying to login to a new user, I get this message in /var/log/mail.log - 

Jan 17 13:40:48 mail roundcube: <cmj1ar16> IMAP Error: Login failed for paco@internetizable.com from 83.165.43.115. LOGIN: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information. in /opt/www/roundcubemail-1.3.0/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php on line 196 (POST /mail/?_task=login&_action=login)